# Routing List Empty, and cant add using SQL either

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019, read-only-routing

**Question:**

Why is my routing list empty? I have removed the secondary from the AG and re-added back, everything is healthy and synchronized. lets assume for the example that server1 is currently the primary. What can I check or try to troubleshoot?

This works fine in our development environment but not in others.

(Last picture shows what I see in development environment)

[image: image of AG settings]

[image: Picture of AG Dashboard everything is healthy no issues]

[image: as you can see the boxes are empty]

[image: Development Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

> Why is my routing list empty?

Looks like it wasn't configured.

In your screenshot below, there is no read-only routing url specified so you won't be able to add that to the list. Put in a correct read-only routing URL for each instance and you'll be able to manipulate the routing list.

[image: Empty read-only routing URL]

Comment: I will try that today, thanks I was thinking the answer might be something I was overlooking!!